# Laravel root@localhost access is denied on server after a composer dependency installation

Tags: laravel, composer-php, prerender, hostmonster

I installed prerender.io dependency through composer and things looked great locally.

Now uploading to hostmonster shared server was a disaster. my website post select statement request was denied for root@localhost. I believe this is what I used for previously for host monster according to my backups, here are things I tried to resolve the issue and it all failed:

1.I tried to create a user through host monster and enter its credentials although my backup had root@localhost and it did not work.
2.Composer dump-autoload -> didn't work
3. php artisan config:clear -> did not work
4. delete and reimport database -> did not work

I would appreciate assistance, I am having a live website and its down!

Note, you could test it through this link: http://www.myqourse.com/TRY

Comment: Are you using linux ?

Comment: locally am using Mac OS latest version (and larval 5.6) and it works perfectly on my machine. but its uploaded to hostmonster and that one has an issue. Please visit myQourse.com to check the error in the post.

Comment: also i just added html push state and tried to remove it ( <meta name="fragment" content="!">
)

Comment: I believe this could be a highly valuable info: when I first ran update, I received blank html with no errors. Now I find this in the docs of pretender.io "Common Problems:
Are you only getting <html><head></head><body></body></html>?

You are probably on Rails or some other framework that uses blocking I/O. You need to switch to a server (like Unicorn or Puma) that lets you start multiple processes or use non-blocking I/O so that there isn't a deadlock when Prerender tries to render your page on the fly."

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i guess I figured it out: just made a user with a password and it got solved. Nevertheless, when i tried to grant access to select statement to a user it gave an errer first time so I guess hostmonster shares the blame :|